# Mongodb connection working on local failing on server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am able to connect to mongodb using mongoose library in nodejs.

```
mongoose.connect(URL, mongoConfig);
```

This code is working on local but it shows following error in k8s server.

```
"ok": 0,
"code": 13,
"codeName": "Unauthorized"
```

Comment: Maybe this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63754742/authentication-failure-while-trying-to-save-to-mongodb/63755470#63755470

Comment: Is authentication enabled in the local server?  enableLocalhostAuthBypass is enabled by default, so if no users have been created, connections from localhost will be authorized without authenticating.